# How to run an exe in hidden mode in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vb.net

I'm converting my vb.net app in javascript and I don't know how to run an exe in hidden mode in js.
Here is my vb.net code:

```
        Dim p As Process = New Process()
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\myExecutable.exe"
        If HideWindow.Checked = True Then
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        Else
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        End If
        p.Start()
```

Is someone able to help me to do it in JS?

Thanks.

Comment: `in JS?`  Are we talking `node.js`, as browser JS it's not possible for security reasons.

Comment: Yes with NodeJS, sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using node.js, I would suggest to use the `child_process.execFile` ([see reference](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback)) function for this purpose. It offers an option `windowsHide` that allows you to hide the subprocess console window.

Comment: windowsHide is hiding the .exe window or a new console window created by child_process.execFile command?

Comment: It hides the new console window that is created by windows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I really want to hide the exe, not a new console opened by a command. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hide the exe"? Do you want to hide a GUI created by the program?

Answer (score 1):

Since VB.net is windows specific you could use .NET wrappers over Win32 API like Process API.

JavaScript is OS agnostic therefore you will not find such windows specific features there. You can however use a npm library that exposes C Win32 API to Node.JS like `win32-api`. Then you can simply do it like you would do it in C/C++ - I.e. `CreateProcess` function.